# Proof of a sequence with recursion

Tags: sequences-and-series, recursion

The problem asks to prove the following to be true.

$$F^2_{n+1} - F_{n+1} F_n - F_n^2 = (-1)^n$$

Anyway, I've tried looking at this or similar proofs for going on an hour now, pretty much the only thing I think I need to do is induction?  So I would be setting n=k+1 but even just trying a base case (using 3) that leaves me with $$F^2_4 - F_4F_3 - F^2_3 = -1$$ which doesn't really get me anywhere.  Do I need to somehow figure out a value to test for F?  If so, any pointers/direction on how to pick a value of F or if I'm going at this the entirely wrong way will be very much appreciated, thanks in advance guys.

Comment: So I think you have: $F_{n + 1}^2 - F_{n + 1}F_n - F_n^2 = (-1)^n$.  What is $F_n$ supposed to be or are you trying to find the sequence $F_n$?

Comment: Use `{}` to group stuff in $\LaTeX$/MathJax, `F_{n+1}` gives $F_{n+1}$.

Comment: What are the initial two values of $F_0$ and $F_1$? Or is it given that ${F_1}^2-{F_1}{F_0}-{F_0}^2={(-1)}^0$?

Comment: Assuming that $F_n$ denotes $n$-th Fibonacci number, here's a little hint: Rewrite all $F_{n+1}$ into $F_n + F_{n-1}$ and see what cancels out and what remains.

Comment: First, thanks to @DanielFischer for the formatting, secondly, totally didn't cross my mind that this was for Fibonacci numbers haha, so simplifying as you suggested leaves me with $$F_n-1 = (-1)^n$$ which I think just about does it?  Thanks for the help getting me here.

Answer (score 3):

For induction: Let $f_n$ the term of order $n$ in the Fibonacci sequence $(1,1,2,3,5,8,...)$.

First, if $k=1$, ok:
$$f_2^2-f_2\cdot f_1-f_1^2=-1=(-1)^1. $$

Second, suppose that the equality is true for $n=k$, i.e., is true that
$$f_{k+1}^2-f_{k+1}\cdot f_k-f_k^2=(-1)^k. $$
We need to show that is true for $n=k+1$, i.e., to show that 
$$f_{k+2}^2-f_{k+2}f_{k+1} -f_{k+1}^2=(-1)^{k+1}.$$
Indeed, as $f_{n+1}=f_{n}+f_{n-1}$ is true $\forall n\geq 1$,
$$f_{k+2}^2-f_{k+2}f_{k+1} -f_{k+1}^2=(f_{k+1}+f_k)^2-(f_{k+1}+f_k)f_{k+1}-f_{k+1}^2 =$$
$$=f_{k+1}^2+2f_{k+1}f_k+f_k^2-f_{k+1}^2-f_{k+1}f_k-f_{k+1}^2 =$$
$$=-f_{k+1}^2+f_{k+1}f_k+f_k^2=-(f_{k+1}^2-f_{k+1}f_k+f_k^2)=-(-1)^k=(-1)^{k+1}. $$

Therefore, the result follows by induction, i.e., the equality is true.

Note: the key to the resolution was to transform the $ f_ {k +2} $ in terms of $ f_ {k +1} $ and $  f_k$.

Comment: I think you meant *that the equality is true...*

Comment: Yes, that's right!

Comment: Actually, I was talking about *Second, suppose that the inequality is true...*

Comment: ok, I corrected up, thanks.

Comment: You are welcome :)